# Using Calculate Value to Replace UTM83 to NAD83 in file name within Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I am looking to use the Calculate Value tool to replace the UTM83.sid input aerial file name with an output aerial file name using the new projected coordinate system of NAD83.jp2

[image: ![Example Model]

What do I use for an expression to get the desired result?
Is the replace expression applicable?

[image: Calculate Value Expression]

Comment: Sorry what is the problem? You current code would turn a name such as fed_utm83 into fred_NAD83 is that what you want?

Comment: No I am looking to have Arcmap take the utm83.sid text out and replace it with the NAD83.jp2 text.  So I am projecting the raster into a different coordinate system and I want the output file name to reflect the new coordinate system.  Thanks.

Comment: Show us how you have set up the project raster tool.